# Can one Test case is depend on multiple Test Scenarios?

Tags: testing, software-quality

Can one Test case is depend on multiple Test Scenarios ?

> we write test cases on the basis of Test Scenarios.
>   there can be one is to many relationship in this situation 
>   So is there possibilities that we can derive or link one test case to multiple test scenarios?????

Answer (score 0):

It solely depends on what you are testing. It is possible that one test case can be derived from multiple test scenarios. It depends on what you are testing.

Comment: Can you give me one example for better understanding  ?